# UITableView doesn't reload until scrolled using Master Detail App in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uikit

I created a master detail app and the table is loaded with data from a url request.
 
I call `reloadData` to reload the table after the url request. 
It only redraws the table when I scroll it. 
I checked that my array is filled with the right data before the reload data is called. I am using a `UISearchBar` to look for data. (I am not using the search display controller, just a `UISearchBar`).  When I load the data and scroll, it works. However, the table does not clean out and load the data on it's own when I call `reloadData`. Here's the gist of my code. I am getting near by pizza places with the Google Places API.

**MasterViewController.swift**

```
    func searchForPizzaWith(#lat:JSValue,long:JSValue) {...
        places = []
    var nsURL = NSURL(string: pizzaURL)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL) {
        (data,response,error) in
        var placeResponse = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        ...
        // some jason parsing here. places array is created. 
        ...
            for place in places.array.value! {
                let place = Place(name: place["name"].string.value!,
                    icon: place["icon"].string.value!,
                    address: place["vicinity"].string.value!,
                    placeID: place["id"].string.value!)
                self.places.append(place)
                println("added")
            }
        }
        println(self.places.count)  // prints 20
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `reloadData()` from the main thread.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( `override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { self.myTable.reloadData() }) }`

Comment: @AlbertBori Did you hook up dataSource and delegate to the correct classes?

Comment: Yes. it loads fine when initially viewed, but shows blank when unwound from another view (until you scroll).

Comment: @AlbertBori You may want to open a new question, and copy and paste your relevant code in there.